# Missing id of message thread in message (accepts_nested_attributes_for)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have two models:

```
class MessageThread < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages
    attr_accessible :messages_attributes, :subject
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
end
```

and

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :message_thread
    belongs_to :sender, :polymorphic => true
    attr_accessible :sender_id, :sender_type, :sender, :content
end
```

In my `new.html.erb` view, things look like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @message_thread do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :subject, :label => t('message.subject')%>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :messages do |m| %>
        <%= m.input :content , :label => t('message.content') %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.button :submit, t('message.send_message') %>
<% end %>
```

In my `MessageThreadsController` things look like this:

```
def new
   @message_thread = MessageThread.new
   @message_thread.messages.build
end

def create
   @message_thread = MessageThread.new(params[:message_thread])
   @message_thread.save!
end
```

The error I'm getting is `Message thread can't be blank`. How am I suppose to set this `message_thread_id` if I don't know which will it be before saving the `@message_thread`? I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your `message_threads` table doesnt have any column?

Comment: Originally it didn't. I recently changed the subject to be an attribute of the message thread and not the message. Either way, that wasn't the issue rails was complaining to me about...

Comment: Quite interesting.. im gonna try it out myself.